# How can I decrease the viewport size of my app to 67% of chrome browser view?

Tags: html, css, angular, viewport, scss-mixins

I have an Angular application that has recently been bought with 100s of scss files. When the application is rendered in the browser which is set to 100% it looks ugly and zoomed in too much.

If I use `zoom: 70%;` on the index.html body it looks okay. But some parts like `material dropdown mat-select` go beyond the screen.

I do not want to trace these `media queries` across 100s of files.

Do you know how can I fix it directly ? Any tricks so that the viewport of the application will be 67% of the browser which is the best view possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is a CSS '[zoom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom)' property, but not all browsers are [supported](https://caniuse.com/?search=zoom). I think it is a bad practice and don't recommend it.

```
.zoom {
  zoom: 67%;
}
```

Comment: Where to put the zoom in index.html ? I tried this previously before the question, but the mat-select behaves wierdly. the option panel is yet displayed in its place of 100% view. other components go beyond screen if I put zoom on the body tag.

Comment: I need the browser 100% and the app 67% of the browser. That is to say, the app should be displayed as if the browser size is 67%.The question is how to enforce this in index.html or the global styles.scss.

Answer (score 0):

change initial-scale in meta tag like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.67" />
```

Comment: it does not make any effect. The browser is 100%. The app is yet 100%. I need the browser 100% and the app 67%. The question is how to enforce this in index.html or the global styles.scss.